# How to store a billion different integers?

Tags: python, optimization, memory, data-structures, storage

I need to store 1 billion integers e.g. 1-1000000000. I need to store it in such a way that when I make a file out of it, the files takes no more 1 GB. Creating a set: {1, 2, 3 ... 999999998, 999999999, 1000000000} gave me a file of 10 GB and reading the file, made my computer crash. I also tried making a array of increments: [[1, 1000], [1001, 2000] ... [999999001, 1000000000]] Now I have an array with 1 million arrays inside, but this makes it really hard to remove and add things to the data structure. I was hoping somebody here knows a smart way on how to do it, which is kind of compact and relatively fast. i.e. I need a way to create a serialized money system, which tracks who has which coin witth what serial number, only are there 1 billion coins.

Comment: Numbers are often stored in 4-byte words. A billion 4-byte words is by definition 4 GB. Even if you store the smallest numbers as 1 byte each, most numbers are long and so your file will still be more than 1 GB in the worst case.
So instead of talking about the specific limits here, let's talk about what you're trying to do. What do you need these numbers for? Why aren't intervals OK? Can you not just store the interval `[1-1000000000]`? Can you just compress the resulting file?

Comment: Say I have 3 wallets all of with millions of coins, the coins in the 3 wallets are all different, they are numbered from 1-1000000000, so one person has coins 1-333333333 the other one 333333334-666666667 and the last one 666666668-1000000000. Now person 1 wants to transfer 20 millions coins to person three, because person one has coins < 333333333 person 3 now has all the coins 1-20000000 and the coins 666666668-1000000000 and person 1 the coins 20000001-333333333 I hope you understand what I am trying to do. I need these transfers to be quick and not take up a lot of storage/memory

Comment: They are more efficient ways to store this informations. One is to store who old the coin for each coin and use a bitset data structure (since the order in each wallet seems not to be important). Another one is to store the information by ranges to compress it virtually. But do you really need to care about each coin, and not just about the *amount* of coin? Besides this, having such information directly in the question (with more details) would be good.

Comment: It is really important to keep track of what number of coin each person has. I added the edits to the question. I basically need a serialized money system, that tracks what money each person has.